# Renew webpage when coordinates are received from android phone.

Tags: php, javascript, android, gps

I am trying to develop one project and I need to implement renew feature. I will try to explain what I have in my mind.

User login to members area and press button "Get Location", then request to get coordinates will be send to his android phone. I have done that already. Android phone will send coordinates after some time, these coordinates will be stored in my server, MySQL database. But I need to refresh his members area page that new coordinates will be displayed.

Is there a way to implement this? If there is, could You give me a directions what should I use?

Comment: Is the problem obtaining new coordinates or displaying updated coordinates?

Comment: Problem is displaying coordinates which were received to MySQL database.